# C number of line in the file (UNIX)

Tags: c, unix, io

I'm trying to find the total number of lines in a text file, but it's not working (the final line count is 0 - see below). Here's the code:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1
int lineNumber = 0;
int columnNumber = 0;
char *byteCurrent;
while (read(openFile, &byteCurrent, BUFFER_SIZE) > 0)
{
        if (byteCurrent[0] != '\0') columnNumber++;
        if (byteCurrent[0] == '\n') lineNumber++;
        printf("%c", byteCurrent);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many problems with this code. The first is that you have an uninitialized pointer `byteCurrent`, but that doesn't matter since you don't actually use what it points to (which is just some seemingly random location) but you use a pointer *to the pointer*. When you do `&byteCurrent` you get a pointer to the variable `byteCurrent` which is of type `char **`.

That's just one problem, another is that there is no string terminator in a file. If you get a zero when reading (which is what `'\0'` is) it's because there is an actual zero in the file, not because you get to the end of something. This leads `columnNumber` to count the number of characters in the file and not any column number.

The solution to the first problem is to use a plain `char` variable:

```
char byteCurrent;
```

The solution to the second problem I don't know, because I don't know what your `columnNumber` variable is supposed to count.

Comment: I tried it but it not work. I think I'm confused. Thanks.